# error 405 method not allowed in Internet Explorer only

Tags: php, html, forms, perl, internet-explorer

I'm using a simple Formmail.pl script for a contact form. When I run it it works perfectly on Safari, Mozilla, Opera and Chrome but when I test it on IE I get the following error:

```
Error 405 Method Not Allowed.
The requested method POST is not allowed for URL/contact_us.html
```

I have also tried using a php script with the same result. I have contacted my ISP to check that the method POST is allowed on their servers and they say it is. Can anyone help?

Below is the form code:

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" method="post" formaction="cgi-bin/nms_formmail.pl" align="center" >
  <div align="center">
      <legend >Please fill in the form below </legend>

    </div> 
  <p><br />
  </p>
  <table width="620" border="0" cellspacing="10"  align="center" summary="A form to contact Clare">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="test@test.ie"> <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="A message from your online form"> <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.test.ie/contact_Thank_You.html">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="realname">
          <div align="right"><font color="#0776A0">Name</font></div>
        </label></td>
        <td>
          <div align="left">
            <input type="text" name="realname" id="realname" size="40" accesskey="1" tabindex="n" required />
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="email">
          <div align="right"><font color="#0776A0">Email</font></div>
        </label></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <input name="email" type="text" size="40" accesskey="2" tabindex="e" required />
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="phone">
          <div align="right"><font color="#0776A0">Phone</font></div>
        </label></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <input name="phone" type="tel" size="40" maxlength="40" accesskey="3" tabindex="p" />
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="area">
          <div align="right"><font color="#0776A0">What area would like information regarding?</font></div>
        </label></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="area" id="area" accesskey="4" tabindex="a">
            <option value="courses" selected="selected">Courses</option>
            <option value="individual">Individual Sessions</option>
            <option value="talks">Talks</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="comments">
          <div align="right"><font color="#0776A0">Message</font></div>
        </label></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="45" rows="5" accesskey="c" tabindex="5"></textarea>

        </div></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <div align="center"><input type="image" src="_images/submit.gif" name="sub" id="submit" value="Submit" accesskey="s" tabindex="6" class="buttons" formaction="cgi-bin/nms_formmail.pl" target="_self" /></div>


</form>
```

Comment: It [would appear](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html) as though the server can differentiate based on browser. Therefore, just because they allow for `POST`, doesn't mean that they allow it from IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" method="post" formaction="cgi-bin/nms_formmail.pl" align="center" >
```

should be

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" method="post" action="cgi-bin/nms_formmail.pl" align="center" >
```

There is no `formaction` attribute for `form`. Reference [HTML forms - the basics](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_forms_-_the_basics)

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. Stupid mistake to make.